# Can someone please help me on this one.If zip code is changed account owner should be changed to the sales representative

Tags: apex, trigger

```apex
public class AccountHandler {
    public static void AccountOwnerChange(List<Account> lstAccs) {
        Set<String> setOfZipcodes = new Set<String>();
        Map<String, Id> zipCodeToOwnerIdMap = new Map<String, Id>();
        for(Account accObj : lstAccs){
            setOfZipcodes.add(accObj.BillingPostalCode);
        }
        for(FireBolt__c territoryObj : [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId FROM FireBolt__c WHERE Name IN : setOfZipcodes]){
            if(zipCodeToOwnerIdMap.containsKey(territoryObj.Name)){
                zipCodeToOwnerIdMap.put(territoryObj.Name, territoryObj.OwnerId);
            }
        }
        for(Account accObj : lstAccs){
            if(zipCodeToOwnerIdMap.containsKey(accObj.BillingPostalCode)){
                accObj.OwnerId = zipCodeToOwnerIdMap.get(accObj.BillingPostalCode); 
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

```apex
trigger AccountTrigger1 on Account (before insert,before update) {
    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isUpdate) {
        AccountHandler.AccountOwnerChange(Trigger.New);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Help you how? Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/380212/edit) your question to add additional information on how it is not working (e.g., *exact* error text, unexpected behavior). *(Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in Help Center where, among other things, it says that your question should include, 'A specific, detailed description of the issue ("it doesn’t work" is not enough to allow the community to help).')* And you didn't even say, "it doesn't work!"

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `zipCodeToOwnerIdMap` variable doesn't contain `territoryObj.Name` then add the map vaules.

Wrong:

```
    if(zipCodeToOwnerIdMap.containsKey(territoryObj.Name)){
        zipCodeToOwnerIdMap.put(territoryObj.Name, territoryObj.OwnerId);
    }
```

correct code:

```
if(!zipCodeToOwnerIdMap.containsKey(territoryObj.Name)){
    zipCodeToOwnerIdMap.put(territoryObj.Name, territoryObj.OwnerId);
}
```

Comment: Still not working with this condition 
             if(!zipCodeToOwnerIdMap.containsKey(territoryObj.Name)){
    zipCodeToOwnerIdMap.put(territoryObj.Name, territoryObj.OwnerId);
}

Comment: Can you keep the debug log at this line and check its getting called or not?

Comment: Yup you are right it is not reaching the last line of the code

Comment: Are you getting the data into `zipCodeToOwnerIdMap ` variable?